# How to create new top headers for weebly

Tags: html, css, header, weebly

On weebly.com I always get the same 4 headers for landing page, no header, small header, large header... How would I go about summing all of them up into one header of my own similar to this website?

https://www.revivalgame.com/

They have one overall header and the navigated pages show beneath it. Is weebly even capable of that through it's HTML/CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick Google search revealed Weebly does indeed have an HTML/CSS editor.

For example, a header image CSS rule will look similar to this:

```
.wsite-header {
background: transparent url(%%HEADERIMG%%) no-repeat center top;
width:750px;
height:250px;
}
```

Check out this link: [Weebly Custom Editor](http://kb.weebly.com/html-css.html)

Comment: Ty, I wasn't sure. Got a lot of answers saying that they didn't. Although I still don't know how to head them all into one header.